# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mule/streaming/ProviderAwarePagingDelegate when trying to use Dynamic Ax connector

Tags: maven, mule, dynamics-ax-2012

I am using Dynamicax in mule esb and servlet , creating war file and deploying in tomcat and when I run it gives me following error :

```
exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



root cause 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mule/streaming/ProviderAwarePagingDelegate
    org.mule.modules.msdynamicsax.generated.connectivity.MsDynamicsAxConnectorGatewayConnectionConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.newConnector(MsDynamicsAxConnectorGatewayConnectionConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.java:393)
    org.mule.devkit.3.8.1.internal.connection.management.ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.makeObject(ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.java:50)
    org.mule.devkit.3.8.1.internal.connection.management.ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.makeObject(ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.java:19)
    org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
    org.mule.modules.msdynamicsax.generated.connectivity.MsDynamicsAxConnectorGatewayConnectionConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.acquireConnection(MsDynamicsAxConnectorGatewayConnectionConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.java:293)
    org.mule.modules.msdynamicsax.generated.connectivity.MsDynamicsAxConnectorGatewayConnectionConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.acquireConnection(MsDynamicsAxConnectorGatewayConnectionConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.java:61)
    org.mule.devkit.3.8.1.internal.connection.management.ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.execute(ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.java:48)
    org.mule.devkit.3.8.1.internal.connection.management.ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.execute(ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.java:23)
    org.mule.security.oauth.process.RetryProcessInterceptor.execute(RetryProcessInterceptor.java:84)
    org.mule.devkit.3.8.1.internal.connection.management.ConnectionManagementProcessTemplate.execute(ConnectionManagementProcessTemplate.java:36)
    org.mule.modules.msdynamicsax.generated.processors.InvokeDocumentServiceOperationMessageProcessor.doProcess(InvokeDocumentServiceOperationMessageProcessor.java:119)
    org.mule.devkit.processor.DevkitBasedMessageProcessor.process(DevkitBasedMessageProcessor.java:88)
```

I have tried using following dependency but it gives me Http error 404

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-module-devkit-support</artifactId>
                 <version>3.7.2</version>
                  <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from your dependency and you should be good to go.

By using `<scope>provided</scope>` you are expecting the dependency to be **provided** by the container (Tomcat in your case) at runtime. But tomcat certainly doesn't contain this jar file. Hence you are getting `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: @anjali, getting 404 is a different type of error.That isn't the same one as mentioned in your problem. This means there is something wrong in the code that you have written. But your original problem of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is now resolved.